# What effect do the lights have in Splinter Cell?

Tags: splinter-cell-conviction

In Splinter Cell Conviction does it ever help to shoot out or turn off the lights? In my experiments it seems to have no effect on the AI. What are your results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are harder for the enemies to see when you are in the darkness. You know you are in darkness when your view switches to black & white.

However, shooting out the lights when there are enemies nearby alerts them.

[Source](http://forums.ubi.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/7211014258/m/8941022568?r=5621001868#5621001868)

Comment: What about such cases as when I am hacking the computer in the embassy? All the guys come running in, would it change their alert status to see the lights out?
[I had fun shooting out every light in there one time, but I still died]

Comment: He has said it will put there state to alert. Also if they see dead bodies they will alert themselves.

Comment: The lights being out, whether or not it is done by toggling of a switch or placing a bullet through the bulb, enemies will not be alerted if they are not within distance to notice it in flagrante delicto.

Answer (score 0):

Shooting lights is very helpful especially in closed areas, but like everyone here said the guards will notice if you shoot a light next to them, but then again I personally like that because I can use it as a distraction to lure enemies into closed areas and deal with them, such as at the airfield, shoot one of the lights in a tent while you are hanging and a guard will come to you waiting for you to drop on him.